# MongoDB: How to convert an int array to strings

Tags: arrays, string, mongodb, int, converters

I want to convert an int array to strings.
My int:

```
"key" : 280
```

If I have only 1 integer to change i can use:

```
db.collection.find( { 'key' : { $type : 16 } } ).forEach( function (x) { x.key = ""+x.key; db.collection.save(x);});
```

$type 16 describes an 32-bit integer. With that code all looks fine.

But if I have an array like:

```
"key" : 280, 193, 213
```

and I use this code I get:

```
"key" : "280,193,213"
```

but I want -> `"key" : "280","193","213"`

Have anybody an solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
db.collection.find( { 'key.0' : { $type : 16 } } ).forEach( function (x) {
    var arr = [];
    x.key.forEach( function (e) { arr.push("" + e); } );
    x.key = arr;
    db.collection.save(x);
});
```